# SSIS - Export from .csv to SQL

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, ssis

SQL 2008 : SSIS Package

Exporting .CSV file to SQL Table.

My SQL Table has an additional column : [SortCode]. Value of this Column is appended through a Variable.

Instead of writing an Update Query to update the SQL Rows, is there anyway for me to insert along with export !!

Comment: Yes it is SSIS Variable and i want to map to the Column SortCode in SQL Table

Comment: I need to Combine SSIS Variable along with .CSV File before i export to SQL Table

Comment: When going from CSV to SQL... it's usually called IMPORT. no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new column using a `Derived Column` transformation by assigning a variable as the column value.

1. Screenshot #**1** shows the Data Flow Task configuration.
2. Screenshot #**2** shows how the flat file source is configured to read a CSV file. Note, only two columns are present in the CSV file.
3. Screenshot #**3** shows how a new column named SortCode is added using the Derived Column transformation. Note, the column is type casted as integer using (DT_I4). You can type cast it using different type cast operators.
4. Screenshot #**4** shows how the columns are mapped in the destination. Note that the new column is also mapped.

Hope that helps.

**Screenshot #1:**

[image: 1]

**Screenshot #2:**

[image: 2]

**Screenshot #3:**

[image: 3]

**Screenshot #4:**

[image: 4]

Answer (score 1):

You can use a derived column transformation in the data flow task.  Just add a new column SortCode with a value that is mapped to your variable.  Then in the destination task be sure to map that new column to the appropriate column in the table.

Comment: This comes before DataConversion or After DataConversion ??

Comment: Order wouldn't matter.  Siva seems to have thoroughly shown how to do it though.